# why can not deploy the react app with json-server and express.js on heroku?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, json-server

I am trying to deploy my app on heroku - using json-server and express.js and instead of view frontend receiving the blank page with {}. I have got a basic knowledge about express.js so will be glad to get any help from you.

Below are links and parts of the code: package.json, server.js

[Link to my repo](https://github.com/SzymonRojek/react-sign-in-up)

[Thats a project structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1PYQ.png)

Package json on client side:

```js
{
  "name": "react-sign-in-up",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "concurrently": "^7.2.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.32.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.0.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Package json on server side:

```js
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.5.0",
    "npm": "7.19.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "Szymon Rojek",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "json-server": "^0.17.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  }
}
```

And finally server.js - where I am integrating json-server with express.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const router = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, "./db.json"));

app.use(cors());

app.use("/", router);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build")));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

At the beginning I had only a json-server without express.js and it was good. I could see the page, fake api with endpoint "/users".

Thank you for your time, many greetings.

Comment: `app.use("/", router);` means your React app isn't served. You need to set up your express code to 1. use an api route like `/api/` to serve the jsonServer content 2. change your request URL in your React app accordingly

Comment: `jsonServer` and `express.static` are interfering with each other. You can only have one thing at `GET /`, and right now that's the root of the JSON server _not_ the static `index.html`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe@ChrisG
thank you for comments yesterday - I really appreciate it. Generally I have decided to remove a json-server at the moment and only using express.js. This amazing tech can do everything and now I have a users.json data and dynamically creating data from the signUp form. 
Even afterwards was quite tricky to build the app on the heroku but finally I have it. 

Now I want to learn about authentication - could you give me advice what is the best for start? What should I learn about from the beginning. Thank you.

How can I rate your comments up?